# iOS how get CGPoint of object in collectionview relative UIWindow

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have CollectionViewCell with a UIButton, I want when clicked at button show some view on UIWindow right there button position.

In my TableView, I do this:

```
CGRect rectOfCellInSuperview = [self.tableView convertRect:[self.tableView rectForHeaderInSection:BBPostDetailSectionInfo] toView:self.view];
CGPoint showPoint = CGPointMake(button.center.x, rectOfCellInSuperview.origin.y + postDetailCountersView.frameHeight / 2);
```

How to do this in scrollview?

Comment: Is the button the entire collectionViewCell or just a specific part of it?

Comment: Button inside a cell

Answer (score 1):

My solution is

```
CGRect show = [button.superview convertRect:button.frame toView:self.view];
CGPoint showPoint = CGPointMake(show.origin.x + button.frameWidth / 2, show.origin.y + button.frameHeight / 2);
```